# find / grep command without searching mounted shares

Tags: linux, find, grep

When I used the find command, I almost always need to search the local drives. But, I almost always have super large network shares mounted and these are included in the search. Is there an easy way to exclude those in the find command, grep and other similar commands? Example:

> find / -name .vimrc

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you're using GNU find (as is used on most Linux systems), you'll want to use `-mount`:

```
find / -mount -name .vimrc
```

---

OS X/MacOS provides the `local` pseudo-fstype. This not in GNU find ([fstypes recognized by GNU find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Filesystems.html#Filesystems)).

Use the `-fstype local` option to find on MacOS:

```
find / -fstype local -name .vimrc
```

If you want to exclude only specific paths, you could use `-prune`:

```
find / -path "/path/to/ignore" -prune -o -name .vimrc
```

**Update: MacOS Catalina (Jan 2022)**

I'm two major releases behind the latest MacOS, but some has changed.

First, MacOS now supports the `-mount` option. The man page for `find` says "The same thing as -xdev, for GNU find compatibility."

Second, `-fstype local` still seems to work. The man page Indiates that it "matches any file system physically mounted on the system where the find is being executed".

I did a test with two drives mounted in `/Volumes`, one a USB flash drive (which I think counts as physically mounted) and the other a network drive. I ran `find /Volumes <option> -name '*txt'`. Running with `-mount` returned no results immediately since there were no such files on the current filesystem. Running with `-fstype local` found a `.txt` file on the USB drive very quickly and then seemed to traverse the full mounted drive without returning any files (even though some do exist).

Comment: does that work for grep too?

Comment: I don't think grep has such an option. I usually used `find` pipe to `grep` as shown in this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/80033/command-line-wizardry-spaces-in-file-names-with-find-grep-xargs/80050#80050 . Lately, I've been using `ack` (http://betterthangrep.com/) instead, but `ack` doesn't seem to have an option to search only local drives.

Comment: My edit was rejected to this, so just making it a comment.  Basically the first example is wrong, because you need to add `-prune` to it or it will still traverse the undesired file systems.  The second example I believe was meant to be `-path` instead of `-name` so it will ignore the path.  FWIW... the last example does work, it stays on the "current filesystem" so doesn't traverse others.

Comment: This answer needs an edit... it's now 2020, and this just does not work on macOS any longer.

Comment: This is current up to MacOS Mojave. I have not installed Catalina yet so I cannot update. If somebody else would read the `find` man page and submit an edit, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 27):

`man find` shows:

> `-xdev`  Don't descend directories on other filesystems.

Comment: `-xdev` is the same as `-mount` FWIW... :)

Answer (score 0):

Original question was to find on local disk only, so for the sake of completeness, here's what I used;

```
for PART in `awk '(!/^#/ && $6 != "0" || $3 == "xfs" ) { print $2 }' /etc/fstab 2>/dev/null`; do find $PART -xdev -name .vimrc -print 2>/dev/null; done
```

As long as your fstab is set up properly it should only search the local disks; ie, cifs mounts should have that final flag set to 0.  I included the OR for xfs filesystems when we started going to RHEL7, they should be set to 0 also as they aren't meant to do the disk reorg after so many restarts.

Hope that helps.