# Find the largest file in directory without size in output

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls

I need to find the biggest file

1. Only one file should be listed
2. Search should work in given directory
   and subdirectories
3. Output should display absolute path to the file
   with filename

   ```
   find "$PARAM" -type f | xargs ls -1S | head -n 1
   ```

works but gives me errors like

> ls: cannot access Over: No such file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Let `find` do that work for you:

```
find "$PARAM" -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -f 2-
```

---

Without find, we can use bash's recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
stat -c $'%s\t%F\t%n' ** \
| awk -F'\t' '$2 == "regular file"' \
| sort -n \
| tail -n 1 \
| cut -f 3-
```

The stat on OSX will have different but equivalent options for stat, and may spit out a different string for "regular file".

Comment: Good. I also found a solution with ls:find $PARAM -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1S | head -n 1    The errors were because of spaces: http://superuser.com/questions/80033/command-line-wizardry-spaces-in-file-names-with-find-grep-xargs

Comment: Works in Linux.  `find` on OSX does not support this syntax :(